# Unable to run Django+MS-SQL with Ubuntu and Python3

Tags: python, django

I am setting up my django application on a linux server with apache as webserver. The project has ms-sql as its backend. To connect I have installed following packages:

```
django-pyodbc==1.1.3
django-pyodbc-azure==2.1.0.0
django-mssql==1.8
pyodbc==4.0.26
sql-server.pyodbc==1.0
```

Below is Database settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "sql_server.pyodbc",
        "NAME": "########", 
        "USER": "########",
        "PASSWORD": "########",
        "HOST": "########",
        "PORT": "########",
        "OPTIONS": {"driver": "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"},
    }
}
```

I checked in my terminal and required driver is also installed

```
root@5b4341ff02e3:/# python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyodbc as py
>>> py.drivers()
['ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server']
>>> exit()
```

When I try to runserver I face below issue:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 7
    except ImportError, e:
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is a syntax error because sql_server.pyodbc is written in python2.
What is strange that it runs fine on my local machine.

Have you guys faced this issue? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Remove comma from and then check again. And you are using python 3.6.

Comment: it is a standard library, `sql-server.pyodbc`, apparently written in python2

Comment: You removed comma or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using Docker to create this setup. Since there was python version clash, I ended up using virtual environment, which essentially defeats whole purpose of docker

```
sudo apt-get install python3-venv
```